# How to add persian/farsi keyboard input method in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout

In Lubuntu 14.04 I went to "Preferences> Keyboard input methods > select an input method > show all input methods" but there is no persian (or farsi) to select.

Answer (score 2):

On the right side of your LXPanel there is a small flag or country code.
If you right click that icon, a menu will pop up.
Choose Keyboard Layout Handler Settings and uncheck keep system layouts.
When you choose add a menu of available languages will be displayed.
Scroll down to Persian and select it.  Move it up if you want it to be default or leave it where it is.  Your choice.
Then re-check keep system layouts.
I believe that it will not take effect until the next boot.

Comment: Thanks Rex that problem has been solved but I have a new problem when typing in Abiword when I type in English and persian Combined. Hear is a sample: It types "توزیع utnubuL سیستم عامل xuniL را می توان" When I want to type "توزیع Lubuntu سیستم عامل Linux می توان". indeed English words are reversed.